# Unable to extract words which doesnt start with character c using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a string containing multiple lines with words, and I want to extract all words from the string except those that start with `c`.

I tried this

```
import re
inp='''bat
cat
mat
'''
pt=re.compile(r'[^c][a-z]+')
ma=pt.findall(inp)
```

I'm getting

```
['bat', '\ncat', '\nmat']
```

This works perfectly fine if I explicitly mention 'at'

```
pt=re.compile(r'[^c]at')
```

Output for this is:

```
['bat', 'mat']
```

But it doesn't work using `pt=re.compile(r'[^c][a-z]+')`

Comment: What should be the match in `bat@cat.mat`

Answer (score 1):

Probably the cleanest:

```
pt = re.compile(r'\b[^\Wc]\w*')
pt.findall(inp)
# ['bat', 'map']
```

- `\b`: word boundary
- `[^\Wc]`: Not a non-alphanumeric char (`\W`) and not a `c`
- `\w*`: zero or more alphanumeric chars

You could use `\w+` to disallow single letters.

Answer (score 0):

Set up the multiline flag `re.M` and use the anchor `^` for the start of the line

```
re.compile(r'^[^c][a-z]+', flags=re.M)
```

Comment: The OP does not state that there is only one word per line and that it is at its beginning.

Comment: @user2390182 ok, make sense. The OP's regexs didn't suggest that

Answer (score 0):

As per given scenario we are trying to negate c in the input , so we consider \b boundary anchor as c comes in the start of the word , and also [^] indicates to negate the corresponding characters in a character set , so here [^\nc] indicates character set will match any character except c and newline , and [a-z]+ matches one or more lowercase letters.

```
import re
inp='''bat
cat
map
'''
pt=re.compile(r'\b[^\nc][a-z]+')
ma=pt.findall(inp)
print(ma)
```

Output:

```
['bat', 'map']
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?